# Hola,cuando giro flip x,mi collider se descuadra de mi Sprite,como podría girar el collider junto al Sprite?

Tags: unity2d

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en unity con rigidbody2d de plataformas,y cuando mi personaje se debe mover a la izquierda su box se descuadra.Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Toma en cuenta que el image flip es una unicamente para fines visuales, yo te recomiendo modificar directamente el transform. Te dejo algunas opciones.

1. transform flip = (Rotar en Y 180 o scala  X o Z * -1)
2. Agrega tu collider y sprite dentro de un dentro de un objeto padre y haces flip al transform del padre.
3. Tu sprite sea hijo del collider y haces el flip al transform.

Comment: Si!,lo que hice fue rotar el localscale a -1,la única desventaja que por ahora he visto,es que no puedes modificar el tamaño del personaje en la animación,ya que eso te impide que el personaje ejecute el script de localscale -1.Saludos

Comment: No hay problema, crea tu propia variable de escala_local y la multiplicas por ese -1 * escala_local cuando sea necesaria. o puedes usar la misma del transform.